# Complete orthonormal system

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

Let $H$ a linear space with inner product.

An orthonormal system $\{e_1, e_2, \dots \}$ is called complete in $H$ if $x=0$ is the only element that satisfies the relations:
$$(x, e_n)=0, \ \ \ n=1,2, \dots$$

$$$$

Isn't it $ \ \ \ (e_i,e_j)=0 , \ \ \ \forall i \neq j \ \ $ if we have an orthonormal basis??

Why is $x=0$ the only elements that satisfies the above relations??

Comment: you do **not** have the condition $\;i\neq j\;$ in the definition of complete orthonormal system...

Comment: How is it possible that $\displaystyle{x=0}$ is the only element such that $$(x,e_n)=0, n=1,2, \dots$$ when for example $\displaystyle{(e_1, e_2)=0}$??

Comment: how those two statements cause you problems? The first one says that $\;(x,e_n)=0\;\;\forall\,n\iff x=0\;$ , and the second one says $\;(e_1,e_n)=0\;\;\forall\,n>1\;$ ...!

Comment: If we would take $x=e_i, i \in \{ 1,2 , \dots \} $,wouldn't it be $(e_i,e_n)=0$ ? Or can't we take a $x$ from the basis?

Comment: $\;(e_i,e_n)=0\;\;\forall n\neq i\;$ ...but **nor for all the indexes as required in the condition!**

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok!! I understand!!! Thank you!!!! :-)

Comment: In this question, is the reverse True? In other words, can we add if and only if to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x, e_n)=0, \ \ \forall n\geq 0$$
while $e_j$ does not satisfy this because $$(e_j, e_j)=1$$
i.e., if we set $x=e_j$ and $n=j$ then 
$$(x, e_n)\neq  0$$

Comment: So we cannot take as $x$ an element from $$\{e_1, e_2, \dots \}$$??

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You can take $\;x\;$ an element from the orthonormal system but it **won't** fulfill $\;(x,e_n)=0\;\;\forall\,n\;$ !!

Comment: @DonAntonio Your comment is more precise! Thanks.

Comment: @Fermat I got it!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)